# Detecting similar words among n text documents

Tags: design-patterns, data-mining, similarity

I have n documents and want to find common words that are included in these documents.
For example I want to say (n-3) documents include the word "web".

Certainly I can do this by basic data structures but there maybe efficient algorithm or a way to handle same words with different suffix. 
Is there any algorithm for such purposes?

I am unfamiliar with datamining world. In general manner is there a term used for efforts of finding similarities between different documents? If there is then I will make my research easily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are talking about `stemming`. If you want to use the [R language](http://www.r-project.org/), you'll have to work with the [tm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html).

- [Introduction to the tm Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf)
- [Text Mining Infrastructure in R](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftext-analysis.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FText_Mining_Infrastructure_in_R.pdf&ei=RRmiS6cPjovgBo3f2e4J&usg=AFQjCNFE9fgdErYDaooVYtOvGTwO4firoA&sig2=NTWskyPZZbAQuHhkKm8JXQ)

If not, I can only suggest this [list of text  mining tools](http://lordpimpington.com/codespeaks/drupal-5.1/?q=node/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by producing a word-list with counts for each document, sorting the word-list alphabetically, and comparing two lists.  This is O(n lg n).

Another approach is to use the [full text search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) as provided by your database of choice.